# How to let user download the data in database to an excel sheet file from web application in Java/Struts?

Tags: excel, jsp, struts, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I want to generate a report which includes an excel sheet which is generated from the data from the database . I am using Apache POI HSSF for creating the excel sheet file in the model.

Now how to let the user download the file i have created ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a servlet. Feed `response.getOutputStream()` to POI HSSF to write the workbook to. Most important bit is the `Content-Disposition` response header. If you set it to `attachment`, then the browser will pop a *Save As* dialogue.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.xls");
WritableWorkbook workBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());
// ...
```

Then let the download URL point to that servlet, if necessary with some request parameters or path info.

Comment: hello.. I have a question... how can I link this to POI HSSF... I'm new to this a very simple example would be greatly appreaciated..